# Capture the Beaming progress and show on a progress bar

Tags: android, nfc, android-progressbar, nfc-p2p, android-beam

I am developping an application that uses **Android Beam**. What I would like to know is if there is a way to capture the current receiving Beam and to **visualize** the progress in a **progress bar** so that the user gets a visual feedback of the transferring status.

Thanks forwards!

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible with the current [Android NFC API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html) for Beam. It is only possible to receive information on when an Android Beam interaction starts (through `setNdefPushMessageCallback()`, see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#setNdefPushMessageCallback(android.nfc.NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.app.Activity...))) and when the interaction successfully completed (through `setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback()` on the sender side, see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback(android.nfc.NfcAdapter.OnNdefPushCompleteCallback,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.app.Activity...)) and through receiving an intent with the beamed data (either through a manifest-registered intent filter or through the foreground dispatch system) on the receiver side). There is no way to get "status updates" in between.

Comment: I think the methods you mention are for the sender, not the receiver. I believe the question was asking about getting updates on the receiving side of the push.